# Find an efficient way to perform a MAX, byte per byte, on 2 huge buffers

Tags: c++, c, performance, numpy, max

I need to compare 9 millions of bytes very quickly, in order to keep the max of each byte. Here is what I do:

```c
int bufSize = 9000000;
byte_t *buf = /* ... */;
byte_t *maxBuf = /* ... */;

for (int i = 0; i < bufSize; ++i) {
  if (buf[i] > maxBuf[i]) {
    maxBuf[i] = buf[i];
  }
}
```

It works but I need to cut the processing time by 3.

In particular, is there a way to work with the 64 bits of the CPU?

Do you know if numpy arrays can help?

EDIT: The processor is a **Quad-core ARM Cortex-A57** and the OS is **Linux for Tegra**. I'm sorry, I should have wrote that before.

Comment: I am not sure how 64 bit can help. You can split buffer and process it in multiple threads

Comment: Quick thing to try is `maxBuf[i] = buf[i] > maxBuf[i]?buf[i]:maxBuf[i]` which might help if it convinces compiler to implement it branch-less. 64-bit solution would be more involved. Most performant solution would use platform specific vector instructions (like SSE).

Comment: You should show the compiler options you used and indicate what CPU and OS you use.

Comment: Unroll the loop a bit, so less time is spent on handling the loop and more on the comparisons. For example, for four elements checked in the loop instead of one, first find out how many sets of 4 there are and the remainder to be handled in another loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Frederik we found how to perform these operations using NEON on ARM.

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <arm_neon.h>

int bufSize = 9000000;
byte_t *buf = static_cast<byte_t *>(aligned_alloc(8, bufSize));
byte_t *maxBuf = static_cast<byte_t *>(aligned_alloc(8, bufSize));

// Optimized MAX using NEON, it works on packets of 8 bytes.
byte_t *maxPtr = maxBuf;
const byte_t *newPtr = buf;
int iterCount = bufSize / 8;
for (int i = 0; i < iterCount; ++i) {
  // load 8 bytes
  uint8x8_t v1 = vld1_u8(maxPtr);
  uint8x8_t v2 = vld1_u8(newPtr);
  // max on 8 bytes
  uint8x8_t result1 = vmax_u8(v1, v2);
  // store the result
  vst1_u8(maxPtr, result1);
  // move 8 bytes
  maxPtr += 8;
  newPtr += 8;
}

// Less optimized MAX for the remaining bytes (if 'bufSize' is not a multiple of 8).
for (int i = iterCount * 8; i < bufSize; ++i) {
  maxBuf[i] = std::max(maxBuf[i], buf[i]);
}

free(buf);
free(maxBuf);
```

Our compiler options: `-O3 -ffast-math -march=armv8-a+simd`.

The processing time is now behind 6 ms. It was 17 ms with the initial `if` and 12 ms with `std::max` as suggested by @robthebloke. Thanks a lot, guys!

Some documentation:

- On `vld1_u8`: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0472j/chr1360928371756.html
- On `vmax_u8`: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0472k/chr1360928366062.html
- On `vst1_u8`: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0472k/chr1359125040827.html
- See also: [Subtracting two images using NEON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481839/subtracting-two-images-using-neon)

Answer (score 3):

Pointing out the obvious for a moment. Your code is *selectively* modifying data in maxBuf, which is causing the vectoriser to fail. Simply change the code to use std::max instead....

```cpp
  for (int i = 0; i < bufSize; ++i) {
    maxBuf[i] = std::max(maxBuf[i], buf[i]);
  }
```

... and the code will now vectorise.

Proof: https://godbolt.org/z/rviiKF

The inner loop has been unrolled, and now makes use of AVX2:

```
.LBB0_12:                               # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        vmovdqu ymm0, ymmword ptr [rsi + rax]
        vmovdqu ymm1, ymmword ptr [rsi + rax + 32]
        vmovdqu ymm2, ymmword ptr [rsi + rax + 64]
        vmovdqu ymm3, ymmword ptr [rsi + rax + 96]
        vpmaxub ymm0, ymm0, ymmword ptr [rdi + rax]
        vpmaxub ymm1, ymm1, ymmword ptr [rdi + rax + 32]
        vmovdqu ymmword ptr [rsi + rax], ymm0
        vmovdqu ymmword ptr [rsi + rax + 32], ymm1
        vpmaxub ymm0, ymm2, ymmword ptr [rdi + rax + 64]
        vpmaxub ymm1, ymm3, ymmword ptr [rdi + rax + 96]
        vmovdqu ymmword ptr [rsi + rax + 64], ymm0
        vmovdqu ymmword ptr [rsi + rax + 96], ymm1
        vmovdqu ymm0, ymmword ptr [rsi + rax + 128]
        vmovdqu ymm1, ymmword ptr [rsi + rax + 160]
        vpmaxub ymm0, ymm0, ymmword ptr [rdi + rax + 128]
        vpmaxub ymm1, ymm1, ymmword ptr [rdi + rax + 160]
        vmovdqu ymmword ptr [rsi + rax + 128], ymm0
        vmovdqu ymmword ptr [rsi + rax + 160], ymm1
        vmovdqu ymm0, ymmword ptr [rsi + rax + 192]
        vmovdqu ymm1, ymmword ptr [rsi + rax + 224]
        vpmaxub ymm0, ymm0, ymmword ptr [rdi + rax + 192]
        vpmaxub ymm1, ymm1, ymmword ptr [rdi + rax + 224]
        vmovdqu ymmword ptr [rsi + rax + 192], ymm0
        vmovdqu ymmword ptr [rsi + rax + 224], ymm1
        add     rax, 256
        add     rdx, 4
        jne     .LBB0_12
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I should have wrote that before but my code runs on a Quad-core ARM Cortex-A57 and the OS is Linux for Tegra. Using `std::max` is more efficient (12ms instead of 17ms). I would need to execute that in 6ms. Do you think I miss parameters for the compiler?

Answer (score 2):

You can get a highly efficient solution (on my system [Intel i5-8250U] ~45ms vs. ~1ms) if you have a AVX2-capable CPU and process 32 Bytes at once using Intels SIMD intrinsics ([Intel Intrinsics Guide - max](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=2929,2921,2916,2914,4821,2908,5629,2951,5113,194&techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2&text=max_epu8))

Because 9000000 is evenly divisible by 32, you don't even need an additional loop to finish up.

```
// #include <immintrin.h>, also for g++ add `-mavx2`-flag

int bufSize = 9000000;
byte *buf = static_cast<byte *>(_mm_malloc(sizeof(*buf) * bufSize, 32));
byte *maxBuf = static_cast<byte *>(_mm_malloc(sizeof(*maxBuf) * bufSize, 32));

for (int i = 0; i < bufSize; ++i) 
{
    buf[i] = (byte) rand();
    maxBuf[i] = (byte) rand();
}

for (int i = 0; i < bufSize; i += 32) 
{
    __m256i *buf_simd = (__m256i *) &buf[i];
    __m256i *maxBuf_simd = (__m256i *) &maxBuf[i];

    *maxBuf_simd = _mm256_max_epu8(*maxBuf_simd, *buf_simd);
}

_mm_free(buf);
_mm_free(maxBuf);
```

Because I don't have your data, I create two arrays with random data. It is very important here that they are 32Byte-aligned.

After that, in each iteration of the for-loop I load 32Byte into the vector registers and execute the `_mm256_max_epu8` which basically divides the 256bits into 32 Byte "packets" (so called packed vector) and picks the maximum of each byte (a more detailed explanation can be found with the link above).

If you only have a SSE2-capable cpu, you can use `_mm_max_epu8` with a 128bit-vector.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think your solution could work on ARM? This code runs on a Quad-core ARM Cortex-A57 and the OS is Linux for Tegra.

Comment: @Paleo No, sorry, this specific example won't work on ARM. However ARM processors have their own vector extension called NEON. You could try robthebloke's solution with specific tuning parameters for your CPU to try and use NEON vectors. Fiddling with godbolt might help.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of what you have, there isn't a faster way to do it. Using python's numpy really only improves upon python to give you C-like behavior.

I think your best bet is to use OpenMP. [Here](http://www.bowdoin.edu/~ltoma/teaching/cs3225-GIS/fall16/Lectures/openmp.html) is a simple tutorial on it. Since each iteration is independent of each other, I think your code should look like the following:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < bufSize; ++i) {
    #pragma omp simd
    if (buf[i] > maxBuf[i]) {
        maxBuf[i] = buf[i];
    }
}
```

And then you compile using -fopenmp. I'm not sure if the `#pragma omp simd` line will help much though.

You can also add compiler optimizations. [Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) is a list. Also refer to the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc). These don't always improve the speed though and that depends on quite a few factors. Just try them out and it could seriously optimize your code.

For example, I had an algorithm that was taking a few hours long. After doing compiler optimizations and OpenMP, I was able to get it down to about 30 seconds. But this area of programming can get very difficult and there are so many factors to consider.

Comment: You want the `simd` with the for loop, not inside.

Comment: Wouldn't these do effectively the same thing?